# Links after changing hosting and domain

Tags: permalinks, migration

I am changing hosting + domain name for my WordPress site. For example now if its hosted on 201.0.0.1/mysite and now I want to upload it to mysite.com. This is what I did

exported database from my cpanel
got all files from server using filezilla (public_html folder that has Wordpress root folder as well)
set permalinks option to default and exported all content from existing site.
now planning to create a new database, setup wp-config.php and replace all files in public_html files.
My question is after doing all this will I face any issues regarding page / posts or any other links means it may not happen that I may get some broken links after doing all this. Is there any extra step required with all this mentioned above or is it okay?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to copy the .htaccess file. Your permalinks will broken if you forgot to copy that file.
Also usually I'm using text editor (mine using Notepad++) to open the database file then find all "201.0.0.1/mysite" value and change it to "mysite.com".

Comment: Simply replacing "201.0.0.1/mysite" with "my site.com" in the database won't work, unless both strings contain the same number of characters, because the data is serialized in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Search &  Replace DB, a free tool by Interconnect, to replace any instances of the host name in the database. It will handle setting the serialized data correctly for you.